# git log of a single revision

Tags: git, git-log

I have a commit c. I want to get the changeset of that exact commit c + metainformation and no other one. Is there a simpler way than `git log -p c^..c` to do that?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You can use [`show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

```
git show commit_id
```

Comment: And git show defaults to HEAD as commit_id, so ```git show``` by itself shows the single most recent commit for your current branch.

Answer (score 73):

Michal Trybus' answer is the best for simplicity. But if you don't want the diff in your output you can always do something like:

```
git log -1 -U c
```

That will give you the commit log, and then you'll have full control over all the git logging options for your automation purposes. In your instance you said you wanted the change-set. The most human-readable way to accomplish that would be:

```
git log --name-status --diff-filter="[A|C|D|M|R|T]" -1 -U c
```

Or, if you're using a git version greater than 1.8.X it would be:

```
git log --name-status --diff-filter="ACDMRT" -1 -U c
```

This will give you results similar to:

```
commit {c}
Author: zedoo <zedoo@stackoverflow.com>
Date: Thu Aug 2 {time-stamp}

   {short description}
D    zedoo/foo.py
A    zedoo/bar.py
```

Of course you can filter out whichever events you see fit, and format the return as you wish via the traditional git-log commands which are well documented [here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html).

Comment: If you don't want the diff, do `git show --name-only <sha1>`!

Comment: If you just don’t want the diff, use `git show -s <commit>`.

Comment: What does `-1` do?  Where is it documented?

Comment: @alex See the output of `git help log` under the "Commit Limiting" section. Or see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History#limit_options `-<number>` limits the number of commits to output.

Comment: If you don't want the diff but list of files changed, another way to do `git show --stat <commit>`

Answer (score 18):

`git log -p c -1` does just that .

Comment: What does -1 do? Where is it documented?

Comment: @alex: The "-1" limits the number of displayed entries to the given number, it's short-hand for `-n 1` or `--max-number=1` and is [documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--ltnumbergt).

Comment: Output is precisely the same as `git show $sha` for me on git v2.37.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to filter change by description of commit:

```
git log --grep='part_of_description' -p
```

where `git log --grep='part_of_description'` select the commits that contains 'part_of_description' and `-p` show the changeset of each commit